# how to write in json format, class and object creation, rest API CALL (POST) using vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net-2010

```json
{
   "Record": 
   [
     {
      "Wagon_Details":
        [
         {
         "Rake_No1":””,
         "Rake_No2": ““,
         "Rake_ID": ““,
         "SL_No": ““,
         "Wagon_rly": ““,
         "Wagon_type": ““,
         "Wagon_no": ““,
         "Wagon_flag": ““,
         "Wagon_tare": ““,
         "Wagon_gross": ““,
         "Wagon_net": ““,
         "Wagon_over_load": ““,
         "Speed": ““,
         "No_of_axel": ““,
         "MobileNumber": ““,
         "Weigh_datetime": ““,
         "Status_flag": ““,
         "Remarks": ““
         }
        ],
      "Rake_Data": 
       [
        {
         "Rake_no1": ““,
         "Rake_no2": ““,
         "Rake_id": ““,
         "Rake_name": ““,
         "Local_id": ““,
         "Sttn_from": ““,
         "Sttn_to": ““,
         "cnsg": ““,
         "cnsr": ““,
         "Arvl_time": ““,
         "Line_no": ““,
         "Lead_loco": ““,
         "Actlunts": ““,
         "No_of_wagon": ““,
         "Commmodity": ““,
         "Fois_save_datetime": ““,
         "Loaded_on": ““,
         "Status_flag": ““,
         "Gross_datetime": ““,
         "Tare_datetime": ““,
         "Last_print": ““,
         "Direction": ““,
         "Total_net": ““,
         "Gross_by": ““,
         "Merged_by": ““,
         "Tare_by": ““,
         "Added_by": ““,
         "Weigh_type": ““,
         "Weigh_start": ““,
         "Weigh_end": ““,
         "Weigh_mode": ““,
         "T_id": ““,
         "G_id": ““
         }
        ]
   }
}
```

Any only help me for creating json class and access using vb.net

Comment: What did you try already? Can you share your current code?

Comment: Actually, I am Implement a api using vb.net 2010 which is given below, the data sent to api server in json format.  https://xx1234.34rvfgthy.in:8000/RESTAdapter/XYZ/XYZDetails, User Id-89myjujUSER
Pass-cxrtghyy